# css for numbered navigation and button

Tags: html, css

I want to display numbered navigation and button in same line.Numbered navigation first and button second.now I got it separate line.I attached my html and screen shot.

HTML

```
 <a href="clients.php?i=0">1</a>
 <a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a>
 <form method="post">
   <button name="add"  class="add">Add</button>
 </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Make the `form` `display:inline-block` in your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form is a block element you need to change as inline element element

HTML

```
<a href="clients.php?i=0">1</a>
 <a style="padding-right:2ex;"></a>
 <form method="post">
   <button name="add"  class="add">Add</button>
 </form>
```

CSS

```
form{display:inline-block}
```